# PyTorch Multi-GPU K80s Batch fails for Tensors

Tags: batch-processing, pytorch

My training works for mini-batches when trained on single GPU (default).

```
if USE_CUDA:
    encoderchar = encoderchar.cuda()
    encoder = encoder.cuda()
    decoder = decoder.cuda()
```

But, when I train with all available GPUs, I get an error.

```
if USE_CUDA:
    encoderchar = torch.nn.DataParallel(encoderchar, device_ids=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    encoder =  torch.nn.DataParallel(encoder, device_ids=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    decoder = torch.nn.DataParallel(decoder, device_ids=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    encoderchar = encoderchar.cuda()
    encoder = encoder.cuda()
    decoder = decoder.cuda()
```

### I get the following error during forward.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-227f3e86847c> in <module>()
18         loss, ar1, ar2 = train(data_input_batch_index, data_input_batch_length, data_target_batch_index, data_target_batch_length, 
19                                encoderchar, encoder, decoder, encoderchar_optimizer, encoder_optimizer, decoder_optimizer,
---> 20                                criterion, batch_size)
21 
22         # Keep track of loss
<ipython-input-8-21861d792653> in train(input_batch, input_batch_length, target_batch, target_batch_length, encoderchar, encoder, decoder, encoderchar_optimizer, encoder_optimizer, decoder_optimizer, criterion, batch_size)
21             #reshaped_input_length =  Variable(torch.LongTensor(reshaped_input_length)).cuda()
22         hidden_all, output = encoderchar(w, reshaped_input_length)
---> 23         encoder_input[ix] = output.transpose(0,1).contiguous().view(batch_size, -1)
24 
25     temporary_target_batch_length = [15] * batch_size
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/variable.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
78         else:
79             if isinstance(value, Variable):
---> 80                 return SetItem(key)(self, value)
81             else:
82                 return SetItem(key, value)(self)
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/_functions/tensor.py in forward(self, i, value)
37         else:  # value is Tensor
38             self.value_size = value.size()
---> 39         i._set_index(self.index, value)
40         return i
41 

RuntimeError: sizes do not match at /py/conda-bld/pytorch_1493681908901/work/torch/lib/THC/THCTensorCopy.cu:31
```

one cuda long tensor and one list are the parameter types passed to the encoderchar feedforward.

```
hidden_all, output = encoderchar(w, reshaped_input_length)
encoder_input[ix] = output.transpose(0,1).contiguous().view(batch_size, -1)
```

nvidia-smi shows the following after the error is thrown.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      
|    0     18320    C   python                                         453MiB |
|    1     18320    C   python                                         266MiB |
|    2     18320    C   python                                         266MiB |
|    3     18320    C   python                                         266MiB |
|    4     18320    C   python                                         266MiB |
|    5     18320    C   python                                         266MiB |
|    6     18320    C   python                                         266MiB |
|    7     18320    C   python                                         262MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: what's the size/dim of `hidden_all`, `output`, and `encoder_input`? Also what are the contents of `batch_size`?

Comment: Followed are the sizes 

    hidden_all - torch.Size([15, 128, 500])
    output - torch.Size([1, 128, 500])
    encoder_input - torch.Size([15, 128, 500])

**This piece of code works well in a single GPU env. **

Comment: batch_size is 128

Answer (score 0):

`DataParallel` needs to know which dim to split the input data (ie which dim is the batch_size). It assumes (by default) that the dimension representing the batch_size of the input in dim=0.

In your case the batch size is in dim 1 for the inputs to `encoderchar` module.

So, either you modify your `DataParallel` instantiation, specifying `dim=1`:

```py
encoderchar = torch.nn.DataParallel(encoderchar, device_ids=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dim=1)
```

Or, change the input size by doing this, (moving the batch_size dim to 0):

```py
w = w.view(batch_size, -1)
```

Comment: I tried the same. It's now failing with a different error.

    ---> 16         packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, input_lengths)

    63     if len(lengths) != batch_size:
    ---> 64         raise ValueError("lengths array has incorrect size")

input_lengths is a list with length 128 (batch_size). Do we need to slice this as well ??

Comment: are you calling `pack_padded_sequence` inside your `encoderchar` module? since you have a batch size of 128 and you are using 8 devices `DataParallel` splits your batchs into 8 batchs of size 16 each. somehow make sure that the `pack_padded_sequence` gets the correct batch size which is 16.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling pack_padded_sequence inside encoderchar module. Isn't that hacky? I'll do that.

Comment: i dont thonk its hacky at all. i doubt `DataParallel` can split a packed sequence, so doing that inside your module is probably the right way to go.

Comment: But, this is my forward function. DataParallel is breaking input_seqs, but why not input_lengths??

    `def forward(self, input_seqs, input_lengths, hidden=None):
        # Note: we run this all at once (over multiple batches of multiple sequences)
        embedded = self.embedding(input_seqs)
        packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, input_lengths)
        outputs, hidden = self.gru(packed, hidden)
        outputs, output_lengths = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(outputs) # unpack (back to padded)
        return outputs, hidden`

Comment: can you print out the size of `embedded` and `input_lengths` right before  you send it to `pack_padded_sequence`.

Comment: embedded  - torch.Size([15, 16, 500])
input_lengths - 128 (list with 128 elements)

Comment: yea, you would want to make sure that `input_lengths` is a list of 16 elements. Looks like `DataParallel` isnt splitting the second input `input_lengths`.

Comment: mmm The tragedy is, I can split input_lengths, but, input_lengths is index aligned with input_seqs(embedded), since forward is called on 8 GPUs separately, how can I give the right input_lengths chunk to the input_seqs chunk??

Comment: you could generate the `input_lengths` inside the `encoderchar` module after the input has been split by `DataParallel`.